# What does "ask a new one" mean?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492289/an-infinite-hierarchy-of-sets?noredirect=1) it it written that:

> This question already has answers here:
>   Sets. Classes. …? (4 answers)
>   Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.
>   Closed 6 hours ago by Hanul Jeon, nmasanta, José Carlos Santos, Yanior Weg, Lukas Kofler.
>   (Private feedback for you)

This is incorrect, so I will repost the question. Can I ask the same question?

Comment: I will just add that in this specific case, the OP has edited the question and it is now in the [reopen votes review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1302821).

Comment: Are you familiar with the explicit types of Whitehead and Russell's set theory (in Principia Mathematica)?  If so perhaps a more detailed explanation of what you are asking for would be in order.  If not, a certain amount of research should inform your Question; [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) is a starting place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not repost the question. Instead you should edit the original question and explain how exactly it is different from the indicated question and why the existing answers there do not answer your question.

Once this is done, your original question can be reopened.

Comment: I think the two questions are obviously different and don't know why they thought it duplicate.

Comment: If the questions are "obviously different", Ponta, then it should be easy for you to point out the difference(s) when you edit the original question.